# Google maps combining multiple encoded polylines?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I put all the encoded_lat_lng values for each step of a leg into an array using jQuery.

```
var leg_array = {};
                var enc_array = [];

                for(var c = 0; c <  result.routes[0].legs.length;c++) {
                    for (var b =0; b < result.routes[0].legs[c].steps.length; b++){
                        var lat_lngs = result.routes[0].legs[c].steps[b].encoded_lat_lngs;
                        leg_array[c]={};

                        enc_array[b]=lat_lngs;
                        leg_array[c]=enc_array;


                    }
                }
                var legs_polyline = JSON.stringify(leg_array);
```

Individually they display a polyline but i want to merge each polyline.  I want to get a polyline for each leg of a route.

For example polyline number 1 is `m}zxHikCC?G@G?MDEBE@SHWRIFEFGHEFMTEJCFGRKTEJEJGLEJEHGHCDEFOLEDGDE@GBEBG@IBO@OBW@I?G@GAK?MCQCwBg@[M[GSEMAO?c@@Y@qBNO?y@@sFCk@I[?[?c@?_@?KAe@@aA?M?qA?Y?]@s@La@PmEnAWHq@^k@f@s@h@_A|@w@n@o@j@[ZcAfAQPIHKJq@p@m@j@c@b@aAv@A?a@RWL_@Jc@Hi@PwBt@iE`BaBt@y@b@kC`B_@TKFaB|@a@NG@_@H[BaB@g@@y@BA?_@Ls@^mAx@qElBA@y@Z`

polyine number 2 is `k`_yHcuAD^Fx@?`@BhAJhEH`EJfE@l@J`D@r@FhD@PD~C@~@?H?v@?X?R@P?H@H@LDNBJBJJXLTRzC`

How do i merge them so i can view a static map `http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=500x300&sensor=false&path=enc:$polyline`

This example only shows two polyline numbers, the amount might excede 2000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode the encoded polylines (to latitude/longitude coordinates), then re-encode the new polyline.

- [encoding algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm)

Comment: is there an algorithm i can use to encode the lat/long coordinates?

Comment: I've checked that link i cannot find a script to download or view??